# Oracle Database versions supported by Weblogic 12c

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have been trying to find all the Oracle Databases that is supported with Weblogic 12c.
I have been trying to find it on web, but unable to get the proper list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what manner? As SOAINFRA data store? Connecting via JCA? Something else?

Comment: Consider ask Oracle support.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at these Oracle certification matrix for 12c releases :

[For weblogic Version 12.1.1](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiB5vyj6O3NAhVGm5QKHY9kAS4QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fmiddleware%2Fias%2Fdownloads%2Fwls-1211x-certmatrix-1395408.xls&usg=AFQjCNE2hKTMs-QBmGnr_DXxYyTSBe4twg&sig2=ghoaad3j8HERZNRMP6mdzA&bvm=bv.126130881,d.dGo)

[For weblogic Version 12.1.2](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqobKt6O3NAhVIj5QKHTkuAacQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fmiddleware%2Ffusion-middleware%2Fdocumentation%2Ffmw-1212certmatrix-1970069.xls&usg=AFQjCNGrXHH1mH6vhiGlx0uJ289c3tPhvw&sig2=AT92f5uM47AnHnAg3cPFcw&bvm=bv.126130881,d.dGo)

[For weblogic Version 12.1.3](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipw_q06O3NAhUEmZQKHfQZAjEQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fmiddleware%2Ffusion-middleware%2Fdocumentation%2Ffmw-1213certmatrix-2226694.xls&usg=AFQjCNE12gz0mQoEN40QYDc3pQfgVzqCDw&sig2=Dxcd24krwwLmkk9Mcln-Rg&bvm=bv.126130881,d.dGo)

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic 12.1.3 contains ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc7.jar (checked locally, but also documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/JDBCA/third_party_drivers.htm#JDBCA699))

This means compability with 11g and 12g releases of Oracle Databases (see also http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03)